# PHP function to get data from web service

Tags: php, web-services, json

Im not getting the data correctly. this just gave me nothing!?

```
function getUser() {
    $json = file_get_contents('http://onleague.stormrise.pt:8031/OnLeagueRest/resources/onleague/Social/WallEntries?id_user=a7664093-502e-4d2b-bf30-25a2b26d6021&count=3');
    $data = json_decode($json, TRUE);
    $user = array(); 
    foreach($data['data']['item'] as $item) {
        $user[] = $item;
    }
    foreach($user as $v) 
    {
        echo $v['userID']."  ".$v['userName'].'<br />';
     }
 }
getUser();
```

Comment: Which part of it failed, again?

Comment: What does `print_r($data)` give you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your

```
$json = file_get_contents('http://onleague.stormrise.pt:8031/OnLeagueRest/resources/onleague/Social/WallEntries?id_user=a7664093-502e-4d2b-bf30-25a2b26d6021&count=3');
```

returns not a valid `json` string that can be converted into array by `json_decode`. If you look inside, you will find substrings like:

```
"dateAdded":2011-05-21T00:00:00+01:00
```

`2011-05-21T00:00:00+01:00` here should be enclosed in " to give you a valid `json` string that may be parsed by `json_decode`. So, your `$data` is now `NULL` (that's what `json_decode` returned)

Answer (score 1):

Well, don't just write functions and look at them when they don't work. Use some echo and print_r statements to see where you're having problems.

Echo your $json variable right after assigning a value to it. Does it contain the data? If yes, print_r the $data variable. Is it an array formatted as expected?